# iterate through select dropdowns with same class name to find selection of specific option

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, select

I want to search through a select boxes with same class name, to discover if anyone has selected a specific option...

```
<select class='myclass' id='instance1'>
  <option value="volvo">Volvo</option>
  <option value="saab">Saab</option>
  <option value="mercedes">Mercedes</option>
  <option value="audi">Audi</option>
</select> 

 <select class='myclass' id='instance2'>
  <option value="volvo">Volvo</option>
  <option value="saab">Saab</option>
  <option value="mercedes">Mercedes</option>
  <option value="audi">Audi</option>
</select> 


 <select class='myclass' id='instance3'>
  <option value="volvo">Volvo</option>
  <option value="saab">Saab</option>
  <option value="mercedes">Mercedes</option>
  <option value="audi">Audi</option>
</select> 

<script>

$('.myclass').each(function(i, obj) {
        // if anyone wants an audi, let me know
        if (something == 'audi')
            alert("found!");
 });
```

Comment: who are these "off-topic" gods.  Notes in code indicate where user is having problem. This is unique, minimal, complete and verifiable question with 4 good answers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply take all selected options with :selected pseudo, and filter them by value. This is cool and clean one liner.

```
$('.myclass option:selected').filter("[value=audi]")
```

Afterwards, you can grab this in a variable, and check if length > 0. (so you have a selected audi option).

Answer (score 2):

This way:

```
$('.myclass').each(function(i, obj) {
    // if anyone wants an audi, let me know
    if (obj.value() == 'audi')
        alert("found!");
});
```

you may need to use the JS code in a function though :)

Answer (score 2):

```js
$('#check').click(function(){
$('.myclass').each(function(i, obj) {
        // if anyone wants an audi, let me know
 
     if (obj.value== 'audi'){
            alert("found!");
    }else{
        alert('Not found');
    }
 });});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id="check">Check</button>
<select class='myclass' id='instance1'>
  <option value="volvo">Volvo</option>
  <option value="saab">Saab</option>
  <option value="mercedes">Mercedes</option>
  <option value="audi">Audi</option>
</select> 

 <select class='myclass' id='instance2'>
  <option value="volvo">Volvo</option>
  <option value="saab">Saab</option>
  <option value="mercedes">Mercedes</option>
  <option value="audi">Audi</option>
</select> 


 <select class='myclass' id='instance3'>
  <option value="volvo">Volvo</option>
  <option value="saab">Saab</option>
  <option value="mercedes">Mercedes</option>
  <option value="audi">Audi</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 2):

You will need a button to handle the detection or alternatively you can `bind` to the `select` change event handler and handle the newly selected option.

To achieve it via a button click, add the following to your HTML.

```
<button id="checkSelected">Check for Audi</button>
```

And then in your JavaScript/jQuery code:

```
$("#checkSelected").on("click", function() {
    $("select[class='myclass'] option:selected").each(function() {
      var element = $(this);
      if (element.val() === "audi") {
         alert('The user has selected an Audi in combobox ' + element.parent().attr("id"));   
      }
    }); 
});
```

This will transverse the DOM and select all selected elements for the comboboxes with the class `myclass` and check if the value is equal to `audi` and alert the user which box they selected it from.

http://jsfiddle.net/0w0v06et/